# timthumb redirecting to 404 in image src

Tags: php, html, timthumb

I am using timthumb in my site and it is working fine in the live site....

It has unexpectedly stopped working on my localhost.. the src to img is given like below....

it is opening when i open in new tab... but not displaying in current page...

```
<img src="http://demo_site/thumb/?src=http://demo_site/uploads/albumcoverphoto/0f5679c495cb3ee55eedf7426b2dc554.jpg&amp;h=131&amp;w=132">
```

when i try to change this src to below one.. it is also giving 404

```
<img src="http://demo_site/thumb/">
```

same url in new tab is opening fine.

any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

You are not loading `timthumb.php` file, Use the code,

```
<img src="http://demo_site/thumb/timthumb.php?src=http://demo_site/uploads/albumcoverphoto/0f5679c495cb3ee55eedf7426b2dc554.jpg&amp;h=131&amp;w=132">
```